# How to invoke ssh with stdin/stdout pipe while allowing console prompt for password

Tags: windows, git, go, ssh, console

I'm writing a custom [`git-remote-<transport>` helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitremote-helpers) following some online [articles](https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/715-virtualization-git-remote-helper).

My helper would use its own transfer protocol when needed, but it may fallback to standard SSH protocol with [The Smart Protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols#_the_smart_protocol).

It means I need to implement the [`git_connect`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9748a6820043d5815bee770ffa51647e0adc2cf0/connect.c#L1415) method from `git` which invokes `ssh` to make a connection and invoke the `git-upload-pack` or `git-receive-pack` remote commands, then pipe the stdin/stdout from the invoking `git` process to the child `ssh` process. Basically it needs to look like the following when working in this mode:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Process: git                      Handles: writer, reader |
+--------------------------------------------- | ----- ^ ---+
                                             (pipe)  (pipe)
+--------------------------------------------- v ----- | ---+
| Process: git-remote-mytransport   Handles: stdin , stdout |
|                                               \      /    |
|                                            (custom logic) |
|                                               /      \    |
|                                            writer, reader |
+--------------------------------------------- | ----- ^ ---+
                                             (pipe)  (pipe)
+--------------------------------------------- v ----- | ---+
| Process: ssh                      Handles: stdin , stdout |
|                                               \      /    |
|                                              TCP socket   |
+------------------------------------------------- ^ -------+
                                                   |
                                                   v
                                            Remote SSH Host
```

It would be simple if all I need is to deal with stdin/stdout handles. But `ssh` has a feature that prompts users to enter passwords. If I just blindly redirect `ssh` process' stdin/stdout with some pipe handles it may break the password prompt feature.

For reference this is what I'm at right now: https://gist.github.com/rixtox/100ed9ac76f835d287813ea44fb4da8c

I'm testing this on Windows:

```
go build -o .\bin\git-remote-mytransport .\git-remote-mytransport.go
SET PATH=%CD%\bin;%PATH%
git clone mytransport://dummy
```

It prompts for password correctly, but stdin/stdout are not piping correctly between `git` and `ssh` processes. If I change the script to simply pass `os.Stdin` and `os.Stdout` when launching the `ssh` command, data piping would work but the password prompt would break.

This problem is especially difficult on Windows because the [Console architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-handles) is [quite complicated](https://github.com/rprichard/win32-console-docs). Even after a day of research on this I still haven't successfully created a minimal working pipe from `git` to `ssh` without breaking the password prompt.

I need to solve this problem on both Windows/Linux/macOS platforms. I'm using Golang for the helper, but a solution in C/C++ using only native platform APIS (libc APIs for Unix, Win32 APIs for Windows but no MINGW/Cgywin CRTs) would also help me understand, so I can try to port it to Golang.

**Update 7/3/2023:** After reading about [Microsoft's article on ConPTY](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/), and went through [their sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/main/samples/ConPTY/EchoCon/EchoCon/EchoCon.cpp), I thought probably something like this is closer, but it's still not working:

```c
HANDLE hLocalReader, hLocalWriter, hRemoteReader, hRemoteWriter;
CreatePipe(&hLocalReader, &hRemoteWriter, NULL, 0);
CreatePipe(&hRemoteReader, &hLocalWriter, NULL, 0);

HPCON hPC;
CreatePseudoConsole(consoleSize, hRemoteReader, hRemoteWriter, 0, &hPC);

HANDLE hConIn = CreateFile("CONIN$", GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
HANDLE hConOut = CreateFile("CONOUT$", GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

DWORD consoleMode;
GetConsoleMode(hConOut, &consoleMode);
SetConsoleMode(hConOut, consoleMode | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING);

// on another thread, stream hConIn data to hLocalWriter
// on another thread, stream hLocalReader data to hConOut

HANDLE handles[3];

HANDLE handles[0] = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
HANDLE handles[1] = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
HANDLE handles[2] = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);

pStartupInfo->hStdInput = handles[0];
pStartupInfo->hStdOutput = handles[1];
pStartupInfo->hStdError = handles[2];

UpdateProcThreadAttribute(pStartupInfo->lpAttributeList, 0, PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST, handles, sizeof(handles), NULL, NULL);

UpdateProcThreadAttribute(pStartupInfo->lpAttributeList, 0, PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PSEUDOCONSOLE, hPC, sizeof(HPCON), NULL, NULL);

CreateProcess(
szCommand,                      // Command name
szArgs,                         // Command arguments
NULL,                           // Process handle not inheritable
NULL,                           // Thread handle not inheritable
TRUE,                           // Inherit handles
EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT,   // Creation flags
NULL,                           // Use parent's environment block
NULL,                           // Use parent's starting directory 
&startupInfo.StartupInfo,       // Pointer to STARTUPINFO
&piClient);                     // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION
```